# Nested Object cannot retain after posting when use InMemory database

Tags: c#, .net, in-memory-database

I have 2 classes where one is nested in another like this

```
public class Account { 
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;} 
    public AccountEntry Entry {get; set;} 
}

public class AccountEntry { 
   public int id {get; set;}
   public date date {get; set;}
   public string description {get; set;}
   public decimal hour {get; set;}
}
```

And use InMemory database like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
{
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AccountDB");
}
```

It adds a record like this:

```
public void AddTimesheet(Account account)
{
     _context.Accouunts.Add(account);
     _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And query like this:

```
public IList<Account> GetAllAccounts()
{    
    return _context.Accounts.ToList();
}
```

When first posting,it saves and the record can query correctly in same request. When post another input, all previous records' nested `AccountEntry` is `null` (`Account.AccountEntry = null`) but the immediate attribute like Name can retain. If it's a scope issue, the worker field should be lost too.

Why only the nested object lost?
Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. AccountEntry is typeof(Input), but i suppose it is just a mistake in the question.
2. EF loads related data (nested objects) lazily. So if you are only retrieving Account, related entities are not loaded. have you tried Include() ?
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager